# How can I draw a line in a figure environment?

Tags: floats

I have put together a figure in Inkscape, however, for the last four lines I wanted to add, the program has for some reason not allowed it.

I'm putting this figure into a LaTeX document in the following way

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Amplitudes2.eps} %Amplitudes2 is my figure.
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-3.83,0.26){\footnotesize{$1000$}}
\end{picture}
\parbox{5.4in}{\vspace{0.6cm}\caption{Caption goes here.}}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the figure as shown in the document:
[image]

This is what I would like to have:
[image]

I just want to add some simple dotted lines (that I couldn't add in Inkscape). I normally add figure labels etc. using the `\put` command as shown in the MWE for the text "1000". Can I use something similar thing for this dotted line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can adjust the coordinates to fit but:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]% include p
\centering
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{Amplitudes2.eps} %Amplitudes2 is my figure.
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-3.83,0.26){\footnotesize{$1000$}}
\put(-4,-1){\rotatebox{90}{\rlap{\makebox[2cm]{\dotfill}}}}
\put(-4,-1){\rotatebox{30}{\rlap{\makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}}}}
\put(4.5,-1){\rotatebox{90}{\rlap{\makebox[2cm]{\dotfill}}}}
\put(4.5,-1){\rotatebox{145}{\rlap{\makebox[3cm]{\dotfill}}}}
\end{picture}
\parbox{5.4in}{\vspace{0.6cm}\caption{Caption goes here.}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```